# Image in a div to change both on click and hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I have a `<div>` with a background image that changes when I hover over three different buttons. Each button reveals a different image. This functionality is good so far, but I’d also like the hovered background image to stay when the button is clicked so that even when my mouse moves off the button, the hover state remains active (unless I hover over a new button). Any suggestions? Check out my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nu3nbkt3/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content-box-column-1").hover(
    function() {
      $('#shows').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/125950112-adopt-second-cat-632x475.jpg)');
    },
    function() {
      $('#shows').css('background-image', 'url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg)');
    }
  );
  $(".content-box-column-2").hover(
    function() {
      $('#shows').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/99059361-choose-cat-litter-632x475.jpg)');
    },
    function() {
      $('#shows').css('background-image', 'url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg)');
    }
  );
  $(".content-box-column-3").hover(
    function() {
      $('#shows').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cathug.jpg)');
    },
    function() {
      $('#shows').css('background-image', 'url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg)');
    }
  );
  $(".buttons").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.buttons {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}
#shows {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #bada55;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: background .2s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg);
}
.active {
  color: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="content-box-column-1 buttons">
    <p>Cat Lick</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box-column-2 buttons">
    <p>Cat on a Couch</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box-column-3 buttons">
    <p>It's a Cat Hug!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="shows" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg&quot;);"></div>
```

Comment: You need to handle the .click() event for the buttons as well to set the background image / css class in there. Of course you will need a variable to track the state so you can "unset" the click setting when a new hover event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want...

You can use jQuery's `.click()` method to bind a click event handler.

You have to store the current image in a variable that changes when you click on a different button.

Also, to prevent repetition, you can use jQuery's `.each()` method to iterate through all the buttons and bind the event handlers to them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = [
    'https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/125950112-adopt-second-cat-632x475.jpg',
    'https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/99059361-choose-cat-litter-632x475.jpg',
    'https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cathug.jpg'
  ];

  var currentImage = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg';

  var $shows = $('#shows');
  var $buttons = $(".buttons")
  
  $buttons.each(function (index) {
    $(this)
      .hover(function() {
        $shows.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[index] + ')');
      }, function() {
        $shows.css('background-image', 'url(' + currentImage + ')');
      })
      .click(function() {
        currentImage = images[index];
        $shows.css('background-image', 'url(' + currentImage + ')');
      });
  });

  $buttons.click(function() {
    $buttons.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.buttons {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}
.buttons:hover,
.active {
  color: #bada55;
}
#shows {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #bada55;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: background .2s ease-in-out;
  background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="buttons">
    <p>Cat Lick</p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <p>Cat on a Couch</p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <p>It's a Cat Hug!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="shows" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg&quot;);"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".buttons").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('#shows').css('background-image', $this.data('imageurl'));
});

<div id="container">
  <div class="content-box-column-1 buttons" data-imageurl="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/125950112-adopt-second-cat-632x475.jpg">
    <p>Cat Lick</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box-column-2 buttons" data-imageurl="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/99059361-choose-cat-litter-632x475.jpg">
    <p>Cat on a Couch</p>
   </div>
  <div class="content-box-column-3 buttons" data-imageurl="https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cathug.jpg">
    <p>It's a Cat Hug!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```